# Pop up box value

Tags: javascript, html

How do i put the table value in the pop up box? Instead of the selected table value, it outputs "undefined"

```
<script>
  function conf () {
    var x, res, y;
    res = document.getElementById('t').onclick
    if(document.formxml.num1.value >= 2) {
      var r = confirm("Reserve for " + document.formxml.num1.value + " persons in "+document.formxml.res. + "?");
    } else if(document.formxml.num1.value == 1) {
      var r = confirm("Reserve for " + document.formxml.num1.value + " person in " + document.formxml.res. + "?");
    } else if(document.formxml.num1.value < 0) {
      var r = confirm("You cannot input a negative number!");
    }

    if(r == true) {
      x = "";
      location.href = 'res3.html'
    } else if(r == false) {
      x = "";
    }
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <style type="text/css">
    .txt {width:50px;}
  </style>

  <form action="" method="get" name="formxml">
    For how many persons?
    <input type="text" name="num1" value="" class="txt" id="num1" maxlength="2">
    <input type="button" value="Table 1" id="t" name="res" onclick="conf();">
    <input type="button" value="Table 3" id="t" name="res" onclick="conf();">
  </form>
```

I don't know what next after `var r=confirm("Reserve for "+document.formxml.num1.value+" person in "+document.formxml.res.+"?");`

Comment: At least take the time to indent your code.

Answer (score 2):

You keep redeclaring your `r` variable within each `if` block, effectively causing the value returned from `confirm()` to never reach the line where you read it.

Try to declare `r` once and for all along with your other variables:

```
var x, res, y, r;
```

and drop the `var` keyword on the lines where you assign values to `r`.